# Is my hard drive dead or ubuntu is Broken?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Can somebody help me. I was watching youtube then my laptop froze when i reboted my laptop it just says: error: failure reading sector 0x100800 from 'hd0 error. It says that for 5 or 4 times then just loads up grub. I dont know what to do. The ubuntu verson is 20.04 lts.

Comment: There are many similar questions on AskUbuntu, examples here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248138/error-failure-reading-sector-0x802-from-hd0-entering-rescue-mode-grub-rescue and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143319/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-failure-reading-sector. It could be a failing hard drive. Consult the answers in the related questions to check your drive.

Answer (score 11):

Try booting from a [live Ubuntu USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install). If that works open the [GNOME Disks application](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html) and [try to repair the HDD partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en). Try again on a partition if repair fails the first time -- for some reason, a second attempt may succeed though the first fails without *specific* error message.

Also, use *Disks* to [check the SMART data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) to see if the disk is failing.

If the HDD is OK, but still cannot boot, try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If *Boot Repair* still doesn't help, you may need to reinstall Ubuntu. Try to save your personal files before reinstalling, since you might lose them otherwise.

Comment: It's generally a good idea if you have important data to try to copy it out as is first, before trying a repair.  Make one last backup...  Sometimes (not uncommonly) a repair works by deleting contents that are not perfect condition.  invalid inode count in /etc, so fsck helpfully deletes /etc/  for you....  now your filesystem is error-free, and useful-free too....